# Swift3 - Ambiguous use of Init

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I converted my project to Swift 3. My code was fine and after conversion I have this:

```
fileprivate func createImage() -> UIImage {
    return ImageProcessor.imageFromARGB32Bitmap(Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(&pixelBuffer), count: pixelBuffer.count), width: framebufferwidth, height: framebufferheight)
}
```

The error:

> Ambiguous use of Init

How to fix it?

Comment: Not for nuthin, but I don't see "Init" in the code at all.  If it's from a dataset, it usually means that "Init" was selected more than once, and had no alias for the 2nd one.  So it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Which "init" is giving the error? The one for `Data` or for the `UnsafePointer`?

Comment: Im not sure it´s not clear,  i believe in Data

Comment: Split that `return` line into three lines so you can be sure which one it is.

Comment: Could you extract the inline object (Data) to a local variable. This way it will be easy to hit the spot where the compiler creates the error.

Comment: Please show how your `pixelBuffer` is declared. Any sort of Array?

Comment: it is declared `var pixelBuffer = [UInt8]()`

Comment: and the error is for UnsafePointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    return ImageProcessor.imageFromARGB32Bitmap(Data(bytes: pixelBuffer), width: framebufferwidth, height: framebufferheight)
```

(Assuming `ImageProcessor.imageFromARGB32Bitmap` takes `Data` as its first parameter.)

You have no need to get an UnsafePointer from an Array of `UInt8`.

Comment: Yes, really i don´t need to get an UnsafePointer from an array. thx very much